# Attaching event handler to class

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I followed this PHP academy tutorial on building JS AJAX files upload script

This is index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dokument bez tytułu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" class="upload">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Wyślij zdjęcia:</legend>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" required multiple>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Wyślij">
            </fieldset>

            <div class="bar">
                <span class="bar-fill" id="pb"><span class="bar-fill-text" id="pt"></span></span>
            </div>

            <div id="uploads" class="uploads">
                Wysłane zdjęcia pojawią się w tym miejscu.
            </div>

            <script src="js/upload.js"></script>
            <script>

                document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var f = document.getElementById('file'),
                        pb = document.getElementById('pb'),
                        pt = document.getElementById('pt');

                    app.uploader({
                        files: f,
                        progressBar: pb,
                        progressText: pt,
                        processor: 'upload.php',

                        finished: function(data) {
                            var uploads = document.getElementById('uploads'),
                                succeeded = document.createElement('div'),
                                failed = document.createElement('div'),

                                anchor,
                                span,
                                x;

                            if(data.failed.length) {
                                failed.innerHTML = '<p>Następujące pliki niestety nie zostały wysłane:</p>';
                            }

                            uploads.innerText = '';

                            for(x = 0; x < data.succeeded.length; x = x + 1) {
                                anchor = document.createElement('a');
                                anchor.href = 'uploads/' + data.succeeded[x].file;
                                anchor.innerText = data.succeeded[x].name;
                                anchor.target = '_blank';

                                succeeded.appendChild(anchor);
                            }

                            for(x = 0; x < data.failed.length; x = x + 1) {
                                span = document.createElement('span');
                                span.innerText = data.failed[x].name;

                                failed.appendChild(span);
                            }

                            uploads.appendChild(succeeded);
                            uploads.appendChild(failed);

                        },

                        error: function() {

                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the js.php:

```
var app = app || {};

(function(o) {
    "use strict";

    // Prywatne metody
    var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;

    ajax = function(data) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), uploaded;

        xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            if(this.readyState === 4) {
                if(this.status === 200) {
                    uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);

                    if(typeof o.options.finished === 'function') {
                        o.options.finished(uploaded);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(typeof o.options.error === 'function') {
                        o.options.error();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
            var percent;

            if(event.lengthComputable === true) {
                percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
                setProgress(percent);
            }

        });

        xmlhttp.open('post', o.options.processor);
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    };

    getFormData = function(source) {
        var data = new FormData(), i;

        for(i = 0; i < source.length; i = i + 1) {
            data.append('file[]', source[i]);
        }

        data.append('ajax', true);

        return data;
    };

    setProgress = function(value) {
        if(o.options.progressBar !== undefined) {
            o.options.progressBar.style.width = value ? value + '%' : 0;
        }

        if(o.options.progressText !== undefined) {
            o.options.progressText.innerText = value ? value + '%' : '';
        }
    };

    o.uploader = function(options) {
        o.options = options;

        if(o.options.files !== undefined) {
            ajax(getFormData(o.options.files.files));
        }
    };

}(app));
```

Now the problem Im having. I wanted to create additional functionality that allow user to delete the file he just uploaded i.e. accidentally.

My approach was to:

- append a button to each file with class `delete` and id being equal to name of the file
- after doing ajax post request `unlink` would delete file based on its name passed via id
- upon finished ajax request js script would delete file from page

since i cannot attach click event listener to class (so i could say `this.id`) im kind of lost with it, dont know how to get desired id based on class with pure js, i imagine that in jquery it would be possible and easly resolvable, but this is pure js so i dont feel like recoding it. anyone has an idea?

Comment: Of course you can attach an event handler to elements selected by class, you just have to iterate and attach the event handler one element at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the issue. If you want to add a button to each file to delete the file, you can attach the event handler easily using event delegation. This means you attach the click-event e.g. to the document which delegates the event to all buttons, may they already exist in the DOM or added later. As example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deletebutton", function(){ ...
```

Instead of `$(document)` any static parent element can work as container element for event delegation.
In the function you can get the ID using e.g. `$(this).attr("id")`. Even if the issue is elsewhere (e.g. adding the event for every single button which can be done), this approach could be more economic.

In case jquery is not an option, it can be done with pure Javascript - just as example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/sLjzzch2/)
In the example delete-buttons with the class "delete" are created by clicking the create-button. Click events are handled by

```
document.onclick = function (event) {
  var el = event.target;
  if (el.className == "delete" && el.nodeName == "INPUT") {
    alert("delete button clicked");
  }
 };
```

As you would add a specific class for the delete buttons, the check for the nodeName could be removed. Add unique IDs for every delete-button, check for the ID in the onclick-function and call the function to handle the delete-click.

Comment: this is jquery code, which i written is not the case, entire script is in pure js

Comment: is it possible for you to include jquery or is this not an option?

Comment: @PatrickMevia just updated my answer in case jquery is not an option